# /me command for chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I love the "action" command `/me` found elsewhere, and think it would be fun to have in the chat. A message like:

> /me loves the new chat system

Would show up as:

> Josh loves the new chat system

Rather than:

> Josh: loves the new chat system

I'm trying to think how it would work with the "bubbles" style. Maybe any messages starting with `/me` would flip-flop the user's icon and name, and would not be in a bubble. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: It's also useful to turn yourself AFK for instance, so you don't have to actually say it in chat

Comment: @Ivo you *do* say it in chat. And it takes up the same amount of space (or more) as actually "saying" it.

Comment: I suppose you can use italics for the same effect for the time being

Comment: /me talks about himself in the third person.

Comment: @Jon, surely you mean "hisself"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay, well this has been a contentious debate but in the spirit of Friday, and the Friday opening a long weekend (here in the US anyway) I propose the following solution, which I hereby make Community Wiki so those jQuery experts out there can improve it:

To add support for the `/me` command, if you so choose, bookmark the following:

```
javascript: var meRe=/^\/me .*$/;var doMe=function() { $('div.message').each(function() {var c=$(this).find('div.content');if(c.length && meRe.test(c[0].innerHTML)){var a=c[0].innerHTML.substr(3);var uc=c.parents('div.user-container');if(uc.find(".message").length>1){c.remove();uc=$('<div class="'+uc[0].className+'"></div>').append(uc.find("div.signature").clone()).append('<div class="message">'+a+'</div>').insertAfter(uc);}else{c.parents(".message").unwrap().html(a); }uc.css("font-style","italic").find('div.signature').children(".avatar,.username,.flair").hide().end().find(".tiny-signature").css("padding",0).show().find(".avatar").hide();}})};void(window.setInterval(doMe, 500))
```

Then, when in a chat room, open that bookmarklet and all `/me` messages will be (very crudely) rewritten.

If you prefer greasemonkey (or the [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) / Opera equivalent), then [you get the luxury of a script that doesn't have to all fit on one line](http://www.shog9.com//greasemonkey/scripts/so_do_me.user.js):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           So Do Me
// @namespace      http://shog9.com/greasemonkey/scripts
// @description    Attractive display for comments prefixed with /me on SO Chat
// @version        1.1
// @include        http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @include        http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// ==/UserScript==

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "(" + grease.toString() + ")()";
document.body.appendChild(script);

function grease()
{
  var meRe = /^\/me .*$/;
  var doMe = function ()
  {
    $('div.message').each(function ()
    {
      var c = $(this).find('div.content');
      if (c.length && meRe.test(c[0].innerHTML))
      {
        var a = c[0].innerHTML.substr(3);
        var uc = c.parents('div.user-container');
        if ( uc.find(".message").length > 1 )
        {
          c.remove();
          uc = $('<div class="' + uc[0].className + '"></div>')
            .append(uc.find("div.signature").clone())
            .append('<div class="message">' + a + '</div>')
            .insertAfter(uc);
        }
        else
        {
          c.parents(".message").unwrap().html(a);
        }

        uc.css("font-style", "italic")
          .find('div.signature')
            .children(".avatar,.username,.flair")
              .hide().end()
            .find(".tiny-signature")
              .css("padding",0)
              .show()
              .find(".avatar")
                .hide();
      }
    })
  };
  window.setInterval(doMe, 500);
}
```

And if anyone wants to roll this code into the real system, feel free! Happy Friday...

Comment: Thanks for the edits @balpha! Much nicer with the small sig.

Comment: Awesome @Shog9, you fixed the bug with stand-alone posts! Thanks!

Comment: +1 Billion.  Very impressive Shog9!

Comment: @Shog: Unfortunately, this not only does not solve the issue, you have explicitly taken it out of the hands of the designers. As noted, my objection was not to the *presentation* of the feature, but the actual feature itself. I basically felt that turning chat into a place where such actions were encouraged would be a bad idea. Now, we will still get users using `/me` commands all over the place.

Comment: @devinb: first off, Josh started this - I just made the code a little easier to use. And second, I really couldn't care less whether anyone does this or not. When my wife gestures with her hands while driving, that makes me nervous, it's potentially dangerous, but `devinb: /me gestures with his hands` - that doesn't really hurt anyone.

Comment: @Shog, I should have checked the revisions. That was completely my fault.

Comment: @devinb: Yes I take complete blame for this -- it was my question and my original answer, I just opened it up to others to technically improve upon it. As far as people using `/me` all over the place, they were doing that even without this script... This script was my way of accepting that this feature won't be added anytime soon.

Answer (score 20):

Live chat is, by nature, a less formal discussion environment.

The `/me` syntax is ubiquitous and extends far beyond IRC.  It is more commonly referred to as an "emote."

```
Emote (v) - to show or pretend emotion
```

Discussions, whether serious or informal, frequently involve emotions.  There is a difference between the following two expressions of emotion, even if it is a slight one:

```
<Diago> I am angry!
* Diago is angry!
```

Considering that `/me` is used quite often currently, without explicit support, I do believe implementing it will be an improvement to the system.

Comment: The fact that users continually do something isn't a reason to codify it. The tag blacklist is a good enough example of that. Not that the situations are the same, simply that the logic fails. Furthermore, on your Diago example, *neither* of those are productive to the conversation unless Diago has previous (or intends to ) give a reason for his anger. A reason in which he would (presumably) use his words.

Comment: While subtle body language and gesture cues are a critical part of human conversation, they are much less subtle when used online, where you have to explicitly state them, at which point you really don't need to pretend to be acting it out.

Comment: @devinb It's not a reason by itself to condone the behavior.  However, without a sufficiently accepted reason for eliminating it, what is the harm in supporting it?  Should I mention XKCD again?  It is fairly obvious that people will continue to use it, whether the display will be altered or not.

Comment: @devinb: I would argue the opposite, that adding a /me command allows for an in-between, a more subtle way of expressing emotions/body language which the medium is otherwise lacking *without* having to actually say something.

Comment: In fact, my example could be modified some, so that posts starting with `/me` are made *less* visible than normal messages. It can be useful even in a serious discussion. `/me is thinking` could, with the right stylization, be a gentle indication that I'm pondering your question instead of simply ignoring you, without disrupting the conversation flow.

Comment: @Josh, My point is that subtle body language *isn't* subtle if you have to explictly type it into your browser. At that point you are simply talking about yourself in the third person, which is generally something that most people find annoying. Chat is similar to the phone. Maybe people find it difficult to communicate nuance on the phone, but they make up for it by *explaining* not by *speaking their nuance*.

Comment: @devinb: Well said... I do see your point.

Comment: @Shog9 What'd I say?

Answer (score 6):

/me would like such a feature

But /me thinks it would be unnecessary.

/me feels that while it would improve the atmosphere of chat, it wouldn't help much--people will deviate a lot from adding good content{*}

/me now feels that it will make the site tend towards Facebook. Not too much, mind you.

/me feels that there's not much of a difference between a stylised bubbly `/me` and a normal displayed `/me`. C'mon, everyone knows what it means. They don't need an extra bubble-visual-cue for that. Use the userscript if you want it.

/me wants a waffle

<sup>*Hypocrisy alert--/me spends *too* much of his time on MSO, which does count as deviation.. But [he has his reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127671/178438)</sup>

Comment: People who refer to themselves in the third-person tend to make me stabby.

Comment: Your *he has his reasons* link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

The "Chat" aspect was created for *discussion*. It was created so that issues which were being hammered out in long convoluted comment threads could be discussed in real-time on in a separate area.

This is in *no* way enhanced by the ability to say "Devin likes ponies". Or even

> devinb: I feel strong about this.
>   *devinb stands up.*
>   devinb: It is absolutely **imperative** that you use a factory pattern. (or jQuery)

Allowing these `/me` comments simply creates less of a "serious discussion" and more of a "carnival" atmosphere, where we are encouraged to `/sing` and `/dance` for each others amusement.

Comment: How does OneBoxing xkcd links add to a serious discussion?  It doesn't.  Doesn't mean it isn't a nice feature for some.

Comment: Have you not been on the chat site yet? The carnival has already begun.

Comment: *comments simply creates less of a "serious discussion"*: chatrooms! srs business

Comment: I agree with what you're saying devinb and you make a strong case against this feature. I also agree with @Jon B -- the chats, while probably *intended* to be used as a discussion, aren't being used that way now `:-)`

Comment: @Josh, there have been some serious discussions on chat.  I think the large number of silly posts on meta prove that we don't have to be serious all the time, to get value out of chat, that will support the main sites.

Comment: @Zoredache: Oh I agree completely, and my previous comment didn't totally reflect that. I guess what I meant was, as the chats are being used now, they're conducive to both serious discussion and a fun, lighthearted atmosphere where we can all get to know each other by letting our personality come out in a way which strictly asking/answering questions doesn't really permit.

Comment: /me stands up and shouts, "Entertain me!"

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution (I tried to make it look as much like the screenshot as possible):

```
function me() {
    $('.message .content').each(function() {
        if(this.innerHTML.indexOf('/me ') === 0 && this.innerHTML.trim().length > 4) {
            var container = $(this).parents('.user-container');
            var inner = document.createElement('div');
            inner.innerHTML = container.find('.username').html() + ' ' + this.innerHTML.substr(4);
            inner.id = $(this).parents('.message').attr('id');
            inner.className = $(this).parents('.message').attr('class');
            var me_box = container.clone();
            me_box.css({display: 'block', clear: 'both', fontSize: '.9em'});
            me_box.find('.signature').css('width', 'auto');
            me_box.find('.tiny-signature').css({display: 'block', padding: '0'});
            me_box.find('.messages, .username, .flair, .clear-both').remove();
            me_box.append(inner);
            container.after(me_box);
            $(this).parents('.message').remove();
            if(!container.find('.message').length) {
                container.remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
me();
setInterval(me, 500);
void 0;
```

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Of course, this still has its glitches, but it (mostly) works.

Comment: Not enough jQuery -1

Comment: While I like it very much, I'd like to see something that didn't work just for me. +1 anyway!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - What do you mean?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff: I would like to see a canonical Mod/dev answer on this.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I doubt we'll get an official answer from a dev :-( I think the closest we'll get is Shog9 helping with my code. Thus, I think you should award Shaquin Trifonoff the bounty :-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't award it to you, I got stuck without connect for 3 (!!!) days, at least you got half of it. (Though I'm not sure why, shouldn't it be to the highest voted answer?)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It's the highest voted answer posted *after the bounty was started*, with at least **2** upvotes. If there aren't any new answers that have at least 2 upvotes, the bounty isn't awarded to anyone, it disappears. See the [bounty section of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).