# /blame feature for chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, chat, fun

Inspired by the [request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) for a [`/me` command](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62979/me-command-for-chat) and [SVN's `blame` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html) I'm suggesting a `/blame` command for so chat!

Why, you ask?

- As a shorthand for the most common chat action.
- Gives users another way to participate in the conversation.
- Allows to tracking of blame, and should allow us to build nifty blame trees and webs.

How would it work, you say?

**Syntax:**

```
/blame userName|soDevs|soe|jeff [reason]
```

Where:

- `UserName` is the username of the person to blame in the @UserName format.
- `soDevs` blames all the StackOverflow developers in one easy to remember group.
- `soe` blames all Stack Overflow Employees, for those times when just the developers aren't good enough.
- `jeff` Blames user 1.

**Output:**

```
UserName blames UserName for Reason.
```

**Effects**

- Each blame is entered into the tables for tracking as part of the monthly blame leagues, and will be exported in the data dump.
- Any user who is blamed five (5) times in the same day loses all unicornify privileges for that day. (Since it is impossible to live more than two days without that privilege.)

I can't wait to see how this makes chat a better place!

Comment: "As a shorthand for the most common chat action" - er....? Maybe I'm just not using it right, then...

Comment: @Marc What are you talking about? `/blame @balpha` is your most common chat action!

Comment: Posts like this makes me wonder if there's really something dramatically wrong with my sense of humor.

Comment: @Has More likely somethings dramatically wrong with mine.

Comment: The only problem with this post is that unless you spend **a lot of** time in chat, you have no idea what it is about. It's the same as with Meta, you don't get the culture, you don't get the memes.

Comment: I could get on board with this, with one small modification: remove the `[reason]` field.

Comment: @Popular Demand, It's already option.  Sometimes we *might* want to have a reason.

Comment: @CRoss, it was a joke comment on a joke post...

Comment: @Popular Demand, C$%^ now I'm even killing *my own* jokes ...

Comment: This question wins. :)

Answer (score 7):

Good idea!

But you forgot one...

**`/blame all`** - when you've just had it with everyone.

---

Also, a

**`/pointfinger`**

would be helpful.

Comment: `/pointfinger` would be most useful as `/pointfinger [index|middle]`.  The default (`index` or `middle`) could be chosen per-user based on the user's upvote-to-downvote ratio.