# Could we have a /me function in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [/me command for chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62979/me-command-for-chat)

Here's a suggestion we kinda thought up while discussing in the PHP chat.

Could we have a `/me` function in chat?

### Origin

For those of us who don't know, `/me` originates from IRC, which basically allows you to post your current action state, for instance:

<kbd>/me went shopping</kbd>

Would generate this in chat:

```
* Madara Uchiha went shopping
```

(In opposition to)

```
Madara Uchiha: went shopping
```

---

So could we have it? It's pretty useless, but it's an awesome feature to have :D

Comment: This may be a duplicate of the question, but the implementation proposed there is far less than ideal.

Comment: Well, it's not an official implementation. You can place a bounty on that other post if you want to draw attention.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: The implementation I proposed there was the closest I could get without being an actual dev... :-( I *requested* official support and was declined, so I shared the code I used as a workaround.